# join columns from merged databases

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, sensors

I want to add 2 columns of a single data frame. The data frame is the result of two single data frames. The code is the following

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("acc.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("gyr.csv")

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

so i have columns id, activity, time, accx, accy, accz, id, activity_gur, time, gurx, gury, gurz
    [data.head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlx7U.png)

```
df["acc_activity"].value_counts()
sitting          32833
standing         31924
lying            31229
running          30429
climbing_up      26938
walking          26080
climbing_down    25281
jumping           4232
Name: activity, dtype: int64

df["gur_activity"].value_counts()

sitting          33267
standing         32546
walking          31912
lying            31822
running          30958
climbing_down    25786
climbing_up      18343
jumping           4312
Name: activity_gur, dtype: int64
```

so I want to have a new column added to the existing ones (SEE DATA.HEAD) which is the sum of activity_gur and activity. So to the right of the data head will be added a new column called activities. This column will have for example the climbing down activity as 25281+25786=51067. so at row 0 of the activities column will depict the activity climbing down for as many rows as it takes. And the same for the other activities. When I CODE  df["activities"].value_counts()it will return me something like the above. after that, I will drop out the activity_gur and activity columns

I tried something like the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'activity': 32833, 31924, 31793, 31229, 30429, 26938, 25281, 4232],
                       'activity_gur': [33267, 32546, 31912, 31822, 30958, 25786, 18343, 4312]})

df['activityfinal']=df1.activity + df1.activity_gur
```

but the resulting column is just the added values and I don't know each sum from which activity comes

can you help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
X = df["activity"].value_counts()
Y = df["activity_gur"].value_counts()
RESULT = pd.DataFrame(X + Y, columns=['TOTAL'])
```

Then to update existing dataframe:

```
df["TOTAL"] = df["activity"].apply(lambda x: RESULT["TOTAL"].loc[x])
```

After above step, Delete the columns:

```
df = df.drop(["activity", "activity_gur"], axis=1)
```

Comment: activity activity_gur
climbing_down NaN NaN
climbing_up NaN NaN
jumping NaN NaN
lying NaN NaN
running NaN NaN
sitting NaN NaN
standing NaN NaN
walking NaN NaN

the results is full of nan values.

a also want to append the new columns to the existing dataframe

Comment: i see your column names are different thats why NAN. I have updated the answer, please try that.

Comment: yes, i try this seems to work. but please look at my data head link. as you can see the first activity is climbing_down, This activity is going for 25281 columns and the begin the other activities. so the new column must have the added values of the two columns but be in the same format as the original one

now i am taking something like that

accx accy accz gurx gury gurz TOTAL
0 -9.66420 -1.65067 0.859924 -0.000977 -0.004135 -0.002487 51067

Comment: I just want instead of 51067 to show the activity (in this case climbing_down) and when I call climbing_down to see its values

Comment: so instead to be depicted  51067 i want to have the name of the activity as it depicted to the columns that are going to delete (activity, gyr_activity)

 id activity time accx accy accz id gyr_activity time gurx gury gurz TOTAL
0 1 climbing_down 1.436000e+12 -9.66420 -1.65067 0.859924 1 climbing_down 1.436000e+12 -0.000977 -0.004135 -0.002487 51067

Comment: so you can drop only one column instead of dropping both. `df=df.drop(["activity_gur"], axis=1)` 
And access TOTAL value for any activity by `df[df["activity"]== "climbing_down"]["TOTAL"].iloc[0]`
(because "activity" column is not deleted.)

Comment: hi thank yoy for the answer. i run  the following

df.loc[df["activity"] == "climbing_down"]["TOTAL"].value_counts()

and the result is 51067    25281
Name: TOTAL, dtype: int64

the 25281 is from the deleted column. why do you think this happens?

Comment: because there are 25281 rows where activity was "climbing_down". And now each row where "climbing_down" is present, TOTAL is set to the sum i.e. 51067.

Comment: please give a upvote (and accept?) if my answer has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

## Test data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'activity' : np.random.choice( ['sitting', 'standing', 'lying', 'running', 'climbing_up', 'walking', 'climbing_down', 'jumping'], 10000),
    'activity_gur' : np.random.choice( ['sitting', 'standing', 'lying', 'running', 'climbing_up', 'walking', 'climbing_down', 'jumping'], 10000)})
```

## The first value_counts object:

```
activity_value_counts = df["activity"].value_counts().sort_index()
activity_value_counts
```

Out:

```
climbing_down    1222
climbing_up      1248
jumping          1274
lying            1193
running          1277
sitting          1283
standing         1227
walking          1276
Name: activity, dtype: int64
```

## The second value_counts object:

```
activity_gur_value_counts = df["activity_gur"].value_counts().sort_index()
activity_gur_value_counts
```

Out:

```
climbing_down    1238
climbing_up      1274
jumping          1236
lying            1262
running          1220
sitting          1259
standing         1247
walking          1264
Name: activity_gur, dtype: int64
```

## Final DataFrame:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'activity':activity_value_counts})
df_final['activity_gur'] = activity_gur_value_counts
df_final['sum'] = df_final['activity'] + df_final['activity_gur']
df_final
```

Out:
[image]

Then you can remove `activity` and `activity_gur` columns and rename `sum` column if needed.

Comment: thank you for your answer

df_final = df_final.drop(['activity', 'gyr_activity'], axis = 1).copy()
df_final.head()

and i get

 sum
climbing_down 51067
climbing_up 45281
jumping 8544
lying 63051
running 61387

so when i write
df_final["sum"].value_counts().sort_index()

i get back

8544     1
45281    1
51067    1
57992    1
61387    1
63051    1
64470    1
66100    1
Name: sum, dtype: int64

i don't know from which activity is derived each value. what I want is each activity to have the corresponding value as my data. head link

Comment: and one more thing please with your code the sum columns is not added to my original df data frame

Comment: How do you imagine it? Can you show me result df you expect?

Comment: id activity time accx accy accz id activity_gur time gurx gury gurz sum_activities 
0 1 climbing_down 1.44E+12 -9.6642 -1.65067 0.859924 1 climbing_down 1.44E+12 -0.000977 -0.004135 -0.002487 climbing_down

so as climbing_down is the sum of activity and activity_gur it will go for 51067 rows

and so on the other activities. in the end i will drop out the activity and acitivity_gur columns

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html),

Like this,

```
new_data = activity.append(activity_gur, ignore_index=True)
```